# How to convert a swift project with storyboards and xibs into a custom sdk/framework

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, frameworks, swift-custom-framework

I'm creating a SDK in which I want to use all the functionality, storyboards and xibs of my Swift application. So that if I want import my application into some other application, then I can directly import my SDK into other application and access all the views and functionality in that. How can I achieve this? Please suggest me where I can find this.

Answer (score 2):

The best would be to copy the existing files -> VC + Storyboards + XIB's and paste them in the newly created SDK. That way you don't need to import one application into another, but import a SDK in all applications, including the one you have created.

Answer (score 2):

To convert an app to SDK/Framework.

1. Create New Project With `Cocoa Touch Framework`.
2. Convert all your `storyboards` files to `xib` file, (because we cannot present SDK storyboards in Parent application).
3. Copy all your classes and import them in to your framework project.
4. Made a Receiver Class `YourSDKReceiver` that will get all information from the
   Parent application and will notify/pass it to your SDK/Framework class and present it xib file into your Parent application.

[Here](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework) is beautiful tutorial to do it.
There is another [tutorial](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/getting-started-with-reusable-frameworks-for-ios-development-f00d74827d11).

Comment: Hi.. Thanks. But this didn't helped me. But I found a below link which helped me creating cocoa pod and converting my whole application into cocoa pod. [https://www.raywenderlich.com/5823-how-to-create-a-cocoapod-in-swift]